# accessing JSON data outside of closure in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, closures

Id like to know if this is possible - In this class, im getting a JSON response, the response.businesses allows me to access the response within the closure. My main purpose however is to use this response and present it within a table view. But i cannot access the data when i try to call it again, even after declaring a class var with the same name. I know this has something to do with the main thread, but i am wondering if any swifty coders know any workarounds, im fairly new at this. Thanks

```
class YelpTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{




    var businesses = [CDYelpBusiness]()
    var names : String?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()





        let yelpAPIClient = CDYelpAPIClient(apiKey: "MY-API-KEY")
        yelpAPIClient.cancelAllPendingAPIRequests()
        CDYelpFusionKitManager.shared.apiClient = yelpAPIClient

        CDYelpFusionKitManager.shared.apiClient.searchBusinesses(byTerm: "Bars", location: "Hollywood, California", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, radius: 10000, categories: [CDYelpBusinessCategoryFilter.bars], locale: CDYelpLocale.english_unitedStates, limit: 5, offset: 0, sortBy: CDYelpBusinessSortType.distance, priceTiers: [CDYelpPriceTier.twoDollarSigns], openNow: true, openAt: nil, attributes: nil) { (response) in

            if let response = response,
                let businesses = response.businesses,
                businesses.count > 0 {

                for business in (response.businesses)! {

                    self.names = business.name
                    print(self.names)

                  //  Prints
//                    Optional("Ever Bar")
//                    Optional("Melrose Umbrella")
//                    Optional("The Pikey")
//                    Optional("Velvet Margarita")
//                    Optional("Mama Shelter Rooftop Bar")
//                    Optional("Mama Shelter Rooftop Bar")


                }
            }

            print(self.names) // prints nil
            print(self.businesses) // print [ ]
        }

    }
```

Comment: From inside the closure, update the data like you are and call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: You just need to assign it to the instance var inside the if block: `self.businesses = response.businesses`

Comment: Why is `names` (a plural word) a single `String` ? Why do you assign a value to this single string in a loop? Only the last value will be kept.

Comment: @rmaddy I Just ran into that problem. I should be assigning it to an array correct?. it is supposed to return all of the names associated with the response i am pulling.. Sorry im fairly new

Comment: @rmaddy when i try to make names an array, it gives me errors within the code. Im expecting to get an array of names back, but as you said - String? just gives me the very last value. Could you please relate another way to go about this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the locale `businesses` variable to your class property.

```
CDYelpFusionKitManager.shared.apiClient.searchBusinesses(byTerm: "Bars", location: "Hollywood, California", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, radius: 10000, categories: [CDYelpBusinessCategoryFilter.bars], locale: CDYelpLocale.english_unitedStates, limit: 5, offset: 0, sortBy: CDYelpBusinessSortType.distance, priceTiers: [CDYelpPriceTier.twoDollarSigns], openNow: true, openAt: nil, attributes: nil) { (response) in
    if let response = response,
        let businesses = response.businesses,
        businesses.count > 0 {

        for business in (response.businesses)! {
            self.names = business.name
            print(self.names)
        }

        self.businesses = businesses
    }
}
```

The above will properly update your property. After this you will need to tell the table view to reload. Make sure the reload is done on the main queue.

This makes your final code something like:

```
CDYelpFusionKitManager.shared.apiClient.searchBusinesses(byTerm: "Bars", location: "Hollywood, California", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, radius: 10000, categories: [CDYelpBusinessCategoryFilter.bars], locale: CDYelpLocale.english_unitedStates, limit: 5, offset: 0, sortBy: CDYelpBusinessSortType.distance, priceTiers: [CDYelpPriceTier.twoDollarSigns], openNow: true, openAt: nil, attributes: nil) { (response) in
    if let response = response,
        let businesses = response.businesses,
        businesses.count > 0 {

        for business in (response.businesses)! {
            self.names = business.name
            print(self.names)
        }

        self.businesses = businesses

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tablView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works so far, but when i get to the cellForRow at function i get an error as follows    
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YelpCell") as? YelpCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.YelpNameLbl.text = self.businesses[indexPath.row] // ERROR
        
        return cell
        
    }

Comment: That's a whole different question. Mark this question as answered and post a new question specific to your cellForRowAt problem with all relevant details.

Comment: Thanks for the help! appreciated.. Yeah i understand the difference now, the dispatchQueue puts all of the data onto the table view! Which is what i needed.